# Including a chart and selection box as "widgets" in other webpages?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, highcharts, widget

My data portal offers the possibility to display data as graphs. I managed to give the user the possibility to include these Highcharts graphs via insertion of a Javascript file - which is generated on my side - in their HTML files. [[Example]](http://geodev.grid.unep.ch/mod_graph/graph_include_demo.html)

Now, I'd like to add the possibility to include Dropdown boxes for the selection of countries to be displayed, at the side of the graph. [[Example]](http://geodev.grid.unep.ch/mod_graph/graph_include_demo_2.html)

However, in order for the user to generate a new graphic with a different set of countries, the request must be send back to our server, and the respond must be send back to the client. I am struggling with how this could be implemented with the least amount of "influence" on the client's site.

JQuery is already integrated in the Javascript file the user inserts into his code. So, I could work with that. Maybe the whole thing only works if the user integrates this in a PHP, and not only an HTML file.

Would this kind of AJAX-call be a possibility:

```
$("#whatever").load("http://remote-server.com/my_script.php")
```

I am a bit puzzled about how to continue.

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 1):

The best option is communicate with the server via JSON. So you catch event on the dropdown, call $.getJSON() to your server, returning json data, which can be used in the chart.

Functions to manipulate on chart:
- setData
- addPoint
- series.update

All of them are documented [here](http://api.highcharts.com)

Comment: Seems to me after quite some searching, that I'll need to work with JSONP, as the "widget" will be cross-domain. Not yet sure how to implement the call with a new selection of countries, and how to integrate the answer into Highcharts. Any examples would be most appreciated

Comment: See the (example](http://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/geojson) how json looks like etc.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery has a built in AJAX method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) that you may find useful.

```
$.get("http://remote-server.com/my_script.php" [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ] )
```

You can pass variables to your server script via the data parameter.  When your server returns data, you can decide how to act on it with a callback function.